# How can I use sub fonts

Tags: css, macos, fonts

Quick Notes:

I am using a Macbook Air. 
I use TextWrangler as a text editor. 
My Macbook version is 10.9.5.

For my website, I have installed a new font called Open Sans. I have styled the body with Regular Open Sans and It worked perfectly fine. However, there is one part of my website that I want to be Bold Open Sans. In the download there were many different types of Open Sans. Bold Open Sans, Italic Open Sans etc... With this in mind, I decided that I would just change the font-family to Bold Open Sans in the CSS code. Nothing happened. Then I tried Open Sans Bold. Still, nothing happened. Can somebody explain what's going on? Also, for some reason, using h1 on anything makes it seem like it's bold. Can somebody explain this?

Here are a few screenshots.

The method I tried to make the letters bold.

[image]

The result. 
[image]

Comment: There is no such font as "Bold Open Sans". It might be "Open Sans Bold" but I'm not sure that's correct either without looking myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have few options, please keep in mind that you have provided **NO** source code and you did not specify if you are loading your font correctly and how, so it is difficult to understand your exact issue.

By the way here some options:

try to use `font-weight: bold;`

```
.dateOfPost {
    font-weight: bold;
    /* you should specify your font type here */
}
```

If you are using Google Font you should include this in your HTML head:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800italic,800,700italic,700,600italic,600,400italic,300italic,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This will load OpenSans Bold Font from Google CDN.

You can use that specific font adding this property on your CSS class

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

---

```
.dateOfPost {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

More infos can be found on [Google Web Font site](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started?hl=en).

Live example:

https://jsbin.com/xawuyuyeye/edit?html,output

Comment: Hmm... It didn't work before with the bold method but now it's working! Thanks!

Comment: @RyanplaysGames great! I am glad it help you, if you think my answer solved your problem please consider accept it.C lick the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows).

Comment: Clicked it! Thanks for the answer! :D